# Reading a huge PostgreSQL table using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to read a huge PostgreSQL table (~3 million rows of jsonb data, ~30GB size) to do some ETL in Python. I use psycopg2 for working with the database. I want to execute a Python function for each row of the PostgreSQL table and save the results in a .csv file.

The problem is that I need to select the whole 30GB table, and the query runs for a very long time without any possibility to monitor progress. I have found out that there exists a cursor parameter called `itersize` which determines the number of rows to be buffered on the client.

So I have written the following code:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=... port=... dbname=... user=... password=...")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.itersize = 1000

sql_statement = """
select * from <HUGE TABLE>
"""

cur.execute(sql_statement)
for row in cur:
    print(row)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Since the client buffers every 1000 rows on the client, I expect the following behavior:

1. The Python script buffers the first 1000 rows
2. We enter the `for` loop and print the buffered 1000 rows in the console
3. We reach the point where the next 1000 rows have to be buffered
4. The Python script buffers the next 1000 rows
5. GOTO 2

However, the code just hangs on the `cur.execute()` statement and no output is printed in the console. Why? Could you please explain what exactly is happening under the hood?

Comment: You need the command:  `cur.fetchall()` before calling the for loop.

Comment: I added a `cur.fetchall()` command right before the `for` loop, but unfortunately it did not help. The code still hangs on the `cur.execute()` statement

Comment: Are you going to be changing the row information before saving it to the ```CSV```? If not I would suggest using ```COPY```. psycopg2 has built in support [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). It would go much faster.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, I'm going to parse the JSON files stored in the database, so I guess `COPY` is not going to help

Comment: ```itersize``` is for named cursors  [Named](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors). You are not using a named cursor.

Comment: To name your cursor, just pass an arbitrary name during creation, like so:  `cur = conn.cursor('somename')`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver
I used a named cursor and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your reply